# I feel confused about the log output of googletest

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

I am learning googletest. I wrote a program as blow.

```cpp
TEST(FactorialTest, Negative) {
    EXPECT_EQ(add(1,1),2); // PASS
    EXPECT_EQ(add(1,2),3); // PASS


  
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    printf("Running main() from %s\n", __FILE__);
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();   
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I ran the program . The log was:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from FactorialTest
[ RUN      ] FactorialTest.Negative
[       OK ] FactorialTest.Negative (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from FactorialTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

I want to know , there are 2 tests in the source code. But why the log showed "1 test from 1 test suite ran." . I thought the log shoule be output "2 tests from 1 test suite ran."

I thought it was a googletest version issue, so I tried versions 11 and 12, but the phenomenon is the same

Comment: You have the only test suite FactorialTest with the only test case Negative. You can list all available test suites and cases with `--gtest_list_tests`. Expectations are not counted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Updated answer:** You are thinking of `EXPECT_EQ` as the test. It is not. It is an assertion. A test performs an action

```
add(1,2)
```

Then it uses one or more assertions to confirm the expected results.

A microtest contains the following steps:

- Arrange (set up what you need, if anything)
- Act (exercise the thing you want to check)
- Assert (check the results)

These are called the 3 A's, named by Bill Wake of Industrial Logic. https://xp123.com/articles/3a-arrange-act-assert/

It's perfectly fine to combine simple Act/Assert into one-liners as you've done. But these are the underlying concepts: an assertion is *part of* a test.

---

**Original answer:**
You have one test containing two assertions. This is the same for all xUnit-based test frameworks.

Almost all xUnit frameworks stop the test if an assertion fails. Try intentionally breaking both assertions by expecting wrong answers:

```cpp
TEST(FactorialTest, Negative) {
    EXPECT_EQ(add(1,1),20); // FAIL
    EXPECT_EQ(add(1,2),30); // FAIL? How will we know if it doesn't run?  
}
```

I expect this will tell you about the first failure, and stop. Sometimes this is what you want. But in this case, it hides useful information. *Edit: I guess this is one of the frameworks that does not stop on an assertion failure.*

To get both results, put them into different test cases:

```cpp
TEST(Suite, Add1) {
    EXPECT_EQ(add(1,1),20); // FAIL
}

TEST(Suite, Add2) {
    EXPECT_EQ(add(1,2),30); // FAIL
}
```

Comment: Your meaning is that no matter how many EXPECT_EQ tests there are in one suite, the actual final output is always 1 test?  Am I right？ If there are multiple EXPECT_EQ assertions in one TEST_F suite， why does the test report always show "1 test" instead of the actual number of EXPECT_EQ test cases?

Comment: *the first failure, and stop* No, expectations do not stop executing test cases.

Comment: I have a general understanding now, thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you call expectations assertions? GTest has both `EXPECT_EQ` and `ASSERT_EQ`.

Comment: They are both assertions. It looks like in GTest, `EXPECT_EQ` keeps going even upon a mismatch, while `ASSERT_EQ` stops.

Comment: Assertion is a condition that must be true, otherwise it aborts further execution.`EXPECT_EQ` does not abort a test case, thus it's not "assertion". https://thisthread.blogspot.com/2011/01/assertions-vs-expectations.html

Comment: Just because it doesn't abort doesn't mean it's not an assertion. Different testing frameworks approach terminate-or-continue differently. Whatever they do, the purpose is "check my expectations" which is exactly what Assert is in 3A.